# Expected response to be an object, but it is

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

Using resource.get() I get this error:

**"Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array".**

If I configure the resource to expect an array I get this instead:

**"Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object"**

Here is what I am getting back if I dump the response from Advanced Rest Client:

```
{
    "Note": {
        "id": "1",
        "clas": "test",
        "obj_id": null,
        "note": "test"
    }
}
```

That looks like an object to me. What's weird is that the page is still working just fine. But I get that error in the console.

**Factory:**

```
angular.module('app').factory('Notes', function($resource) {
    var notes = $resource('/index.php/notes/:id.json');
    return {
        get: function(id, success) { notes.get({id:id}, function(resp) { success(resp.Note); }); },
        query: function() { return notes.query(); }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app').controller('NotesCtrl',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $location, Notes) {
        Notes.get($stateParams.id,
            function(note) {
                $scope.note = note;
            },
            function(note) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(note);
            }
        );
    });
```

That resource is built using CakePHP and that is the vanilla view function that bake makes for you that is being serialized.

Comment: It'd be easier if we could see a plunker. Before that, what might be totally off the wall, but figured I'd ask anyway: can you change the labels in your json? is there any chance at all that the duplication of "note" is causing confusion when the json's parsed?

Comment: I don't know how to spoof the api call for plunker. I can update with code though.

Comment: Ohhhh php. Here's the easiest way to spoof the api: http://plnkr.co/edit/46V2g8rlrwlrAxsZ81dX?p=preview. Just create another controller that puts the json on the scope, and then run the factory on it. (Alternate is to create a static json file and call that, instead.) That'll let you check whether it's the json itself that's triggering error, and if not, at least knock that off the list of culprits.

Comment: That's a great idea. I tried the static json idea and it worked just fine. I also tried a fresh install of Cake stripped down to just the one object I want and that worked as well. I think there is something up with my cake install.

Comment: Yeah, I've had that kind of madness from php before. I'm not sure I'd say it's Cake per se. It's probably more 'cause php doesn't speak json natively, so it mangles it easily, and then angular throws fits. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess just so anyone else with a similar knows there is a solution (or at least the glimmerings of one), I'll do a formal answer here. Seeing how php doesn't speak json natively, it can produce questionably-formed json that angular can't parse. To make sure the issue isn't (or is) the json, bypass the php and spoof the json.

To spoof an api, create a new controller and insert the expected json into the scope.

```
app.controller('NoteCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.allNotes = [{
        "Note": {
            "id": "1",
            "clas": "test",
            "obj_id": null,
            "note": "test"
        }       
    }];
});
```

Replace any reference to the api/json with this new scope, ie change

```
var notes = $resource('/index.php/notes/:id.json');
```

to:

```
var notes = $scope.allNotes;
```

...and then test. If things go right, then it's not your angular nor your json, it's probably your php. That'll at least narrow things down on the list o' troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it led me to the real problem. I _think_ the problem is actually in ui-router. The problem is that it is loading the controller twice per page load. The first time the id that it passes in is null so it tries to pull an index from cake. All I have to do is check for the id before I call the resource. I'll take this up with the ui-router team to see if I can get a real resolution. Thanks @kl02 for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had two requests in the same Angular.js controller:

```
 function UserCtrl($scope, $resource, $routeParams, API) {
   $scope.users = API.Users.query();
   $scope.user = API.Users.get({ id:$routeParams.id });
 };
```

So on one page, you would get the error, but not on the other.

Here is another way to achieve it (that mirrors the Phone tutorial on step 11 - http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11):

```
<div class="container" style="border:solid 1px grey">
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/users/', { templateUrl: 'assets/users/index.html', controller: UserListCtrl });
    $routeProvider.when('/users/:id', { templateUrl: 'assets/users/show.html', controller: UserCtrl });
 });

  app.factory('API', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
      Users: $resource('/users/:id.json')
    };
  }]);

  function UserListCtrl($scope, $resource, API) {
    $scope.users = API.Users.query();
  };

  function UserCtrl($scope, $resource, $routeParams, API) {
    $scope.user = API.Users.get({ id:$routeParams.id });
  };

</script>
```